# How to express the effectiveness of a protection method

Tags: probability

Problem
A Population of totally 187000 chicks, is grouped in 27'300 chicks that are protected (with flattery bands and blinking elements). The other group with 159'700 chickens are not  protected. During one year it is obeserved, that in total 800 chicks are robbed by raptors, 78 are robbed from the protected population, and 722 are robbed from the non protected population.

What is the probability, that
a) a robbed chicken is from the protected chicks?
b) a robbed chicken is from the unprotected chicks?
and
c) What is the best way, to express the effectiveness of the protection method?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a math question, not a programming question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour]. SO is only for programming questions.

Comment: where should I then ask the question, do you have a hint?